# Redirect output to multiple files in a specific directory in for loop shell

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a script that for each file in a directory do something with the awk command.

For that i use a for loop, but i'd want that each awk command running for a file redirect my output to a file. Like 1 source file -> 1 target file.

For the moment, my shell is setup like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES="/home/yha/AG2R/*"

for f in $FILES 
do 
    echo "Processing $f file.."; 
    awk -F ';' '$1=="TABLE" && $3=="" {printf "01 %s.\n\n", $2; next} {sub(/CHAR/,"PIC X", $2);printf "   * %s.\n\n     05 %s %s.\n\n", $3, $1, $2;}' $f > temp.cpy
done
```

As you can see i redirect the output in "temp.cpy" but not only does he only give me the last file of the directory output even if he'd put all my files transformation in that file this is not what i want as i described it at the beginning. I'd also like to redirect the outputs in a specific folder

Answer (score 3):

Make the output file depend on `$f`.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES="/home/yha/AG2R/*"
target_dir=/home/yha/AG2R/COPY

for f in $FILES 
do 
    echo "Processing $f file.."; 
    base=$(basename "$f")
    awk -F ';' '$1=="TABLE" && $3=="" {printf "01 %s.\n\n", $2; next} {sub(/CHAR/,"PIC X", $2);printf "   * %s.\n\n     05 %s %s.\n\n", $3, $1, $2;}' "$f" > "$target_dir/$base"
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much, is there a way to put the output files in a specific directory ?

Comment: Of course. Just put the directory name at the beginning. `> "dir/$f.cpy"`

Comment: I did this : "$TARGET_DIRECTORY/$f.cpy" but i get  "No such file or directory" error

Comment: Then `$TARGET_DIRECTORY` must be wrong. If it's a relative pathname, make sure it's relative to your current directory. Using an absolute pathname avoids problems.

Comment: Yes i also tried with the relative path like that : > "/home/yha/AG2R/COPY/$f.cpy" but i get this : /home/yha/AG2R/COPY//home/yha/AG2R/SOURCE/MOFRASAN.des.cpy: No such file or directory. I dont know why he is trying to get to the source + target directory

Comment: Oops, I forgot that you have an absolute path in `$f`. `b=$(basename "$f")` then `> "$TARGET_DIRECTORY/$b.cpy"`

Comment: No error but no output files in the directory, do i need to write b=$(basename "$f") somewhere ?

Comment: Oh ok, no i am a full beginner. But i understand now. Thank you

Comment: I've updated the answer. You should update the question to say that you want them in a different directory.

Answer (score 1):

awk can do this by itself:

```sh
awk -F ';' '
    FNR == 1 {
        printf "Processing %s file..\n", FILENAME
        output = FILENAME ".out"
    }
    $1 == "TABLE" && $3 == "" {
        printf "01 %s.\n\n", $2 > output
        next
    } 
    {
        sub(/CHAR/,"PIC X", $2)
        printf "   * %s.\n\n     05 %s %s.\n\n", $3, $1, $2 > output
    }
' /home/yha/AG2R/*
```